# Docker still show the version after after its purge

Tags: docker

After several problems, I decided to purge Docker to reinstall it in a second time. Here's the steps that I did to purge all the packages related to Docker:

```
- dpkg -l | grep -i docker
- sudo apt-get purge docker-engine docker docker-compose
- sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker docker-compose docker-engin
```

I even delete the folder which contains Docker files and containters `/var/lib/docker`

But I still display the docker version after all I did.

```
docker -v
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build a04f55b
```

Comment: The package you want to remove may be the `docker-ce` one.

Comment: I did not install this package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT :** This solution is for systems using Debian packages (Debian, Ubuntu, Mint, ...).

You saw that the docker binary is still present in your system.
You can locate it using the `whereis` command :

```
# whereis docker
docker: /usr/bin/docker /usr/lib/docker /etc/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz
```

Now that the binary is located (it's `/usr/bin/docker` in the example) you can use the `dpkg -S <location>` to look for its package. See [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file).

```
# dpkg -S /usr/bin/docker
docker-ce: /usr/bin/docker
```

And then you can get rid of the package (here `docker-ce`) using your usual tools (`apt-get purge`, or `dpkg -r` if the package was not installed through a repository).

Comment: I'd probably use `type docker` to see where the binary is that's being run, instead of whereis. Nice summary of how to do this with Debian packages.

Answer (score 1):

That version number looks like the last release of the snap package. If you installed by snap, then the uninstall uses the same tool:

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

Comment: It helped me .. I had installed docker using snap so it worked only. I don't know why but other solutions did not help me.